# Matching uppercase or lowercase string Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match the last part an an email and am using Regex.

It is working fine using the following `"[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@abc.com$"` but I want the last part of the address to be upper or lower case.

so that that it will match variations such as

```
john@abc.co.com
john@ABC.CO.com
john@Abc.co.com
```

as possible scenarios...so in other words all variations of upper and lower case.

How could I change the pattern to accommodate this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [i flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to ignore case.

Here is some more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description

Answer (score 3):

> To make your regex  case insensitive, add the `i` flag:

```
   /[a-z0-9-\.\-]+@abc.com$/i
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative option you may use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[Aa][Bb][Cc](\.[Cc][Oo])?\.[Cc][Oo][Mm]$
```

It will not ignore case for the first part (ie. before @) more over by your regex it was not matching .co.com it was only mathing .com

By this way you can make part of it case in sensitive

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/DffZNA/6)

Answer (score 2):

Add the `i` flag to make the matching case insensitive.  Here is a working example:

```
var addresses = [
    'john@abc.co.com',
    'john@ABC.CO.com',
    'john@Abc.co.com',
];

var pattern = /[a-z0-9._-]+@abc\.co\.com$/i;

for(i=0,l=addresses.length; i<l; i++) {
    console.log(pattern.test(addresses[i]));
}
```

Play with a test here https://regex101.com/r/wdgUFZ/2